# Send E-mail in HTML format

Tags: android, html, android-intent

I want to send an email in HTML format like as below image.
How can I do this?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance...!

[image: One]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String body = new String("<html><body><table><tr><td><br/>" +header+"</td></tr><br/><br/>"+"Get <b> Best Score </b> in your Android Phone.<br/>"+"<a href=\"" + link_val + "\">" + text_value+ "</a>");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, html.fromHtml(body));
```

Android support only some Tag..

For more information check below link..

[Link1](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html)

[Link2](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Comment: I have tried this thing but don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use any [html editor](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/frontpage-help/) program to design the html page. `emailText` contains the html data. I think this code is fairly obvious.

```
 final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
            emailTo);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, 
                emailCc);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
                subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                emailText);

   this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose your email program"));
```